# Getting 403 on target client's resources during impersonation Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect, impersonation

I am trying to impersonate a user in Keycloak who has the role `user` (tony123) by using another user (superadmin).

Superadmin has the `impersonation` role under `realm-management` client assigned.
[image]

I am also able to generate a token for superadmin in the source client(source-client)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/mytenant/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=superadmin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=c3VwZXJhZG1pbg==' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=source-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=source-client-secret'
```

I have also setup internal token to internal token client token exchange by following the below steps.

1. Run Keycloak with the command line args `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled`
2. Setup token exchange permission in the target client. Add a client based policy with the `source-client` as the client.
3. Enabled permissions on `Users` tab
   [image]
4. Setup `admin-impersonating.permission.users` permissions. Added a client based policy with `source-client` as the client.

With the above setup, I am able to generate a impersonate token using the below cURL command

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/mytenant/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=source-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=source-client-secret' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange' \
--data-urlencode 'subject_token=.....' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=target-client' \
--data-urlencode 'requested_subject=<user id of tony123>'
```

Using the access_token I get from the above cURL command, I am now trying to access a resource on `target-client` which `tony123` is able to access directly. When I do so, I am getting 403 forbidden on the call. I am not sure what I am missing here. Thanks in advance